# Samsung devices have a strange version of Google Play Services and it doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, google-play-services, samsung-mobile, activity-recognition

I am using Activity Recognition API available in Google Play Services.
I've tried using Google Play Services 5+ and Google Play Services 6+ (using the new API with GoogleApiClient) on Android 4+ and Android 5+. Everything works great on different kinds of devices, except Samsung Galaxy Note 4
(Announced 2014, September)(Can not test on other Samsung devices.)
The problem is that:

- Samsung Galaxy Note 4 has Google Play Services 5.0.89 (currently the
  last version is 6.5.99) (and it's not possible to update it)
- [Activity Recognition API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) doesn't work (it's available, just
  doesn't trigger needed recognition events)

Does anyone faced the similar problems on any Samsung devices?
How to resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code, can you show some concrete example of what is not working? A complete example pasted either here, on a Gist or on pastebin or anything else would be great for people trying to reproduce your problem. Also, do you get anything in the logs? errors?

Comment: why is it not possible to update the google play services?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pvllnspk/7f58a6374fa517250e50 - using Google Play Services API version < 6.5 (ActivityRecognitionIntentService onHandleIntent is not called)

Comment: Actually Google 'Activity Recognition' sample doesn't work on Galaxy Note 4.

Comment: Managed to update Google Play Services manually calling GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, this, 0).show();

Comment: It is possible to update google play services thru its Google Play listing,  please remove/cleanup this question.